# GCP with Composer fails running PHP, 'app' is not recognized

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, composer-php

Using Google Cloud Platform and trying to setup [Symfony Hello World on App Engine Standard Environment](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/symfony-hello-world-app-engine).  Deployment goes fine until I try run the app in my local environment.  When I run this command from the root of the project, the instance does not start:

```
composer run-script server --timeout=0
```

Instead, I receive an error that `'app' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`:

[image]

From what I can tell, composer runs the script that is found at `scripts/server.php`, but the script does not run properly.  When I look at the `server.php` script itself, I see that `app` appears in the first line of code, which I assume is the same `app` noted in the error above.  I don't know if that is relevant or not.

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
$cacheClearCmd = 'app/console cache:clear --no-debug --env=dev';
passthru($cacheClearCmd, $returnVar);
```

I guess my question at this point would be:  Why is my PHP script not running properly when called by composer in this way?

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#system-requirements, check installation on windows part . What thoes `composer -V` return?

Comment: Thanks @cske, `composer -V` returns `Composer version 1.7.2 2018-08-16 16:57:12`.  I know that Composer is running correctly because when I run this command `composer create-project google/appengine-symfony-starter-project` it correctly downloads the source code from GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

The initial error occurs is due to it not seeing the command as php, changing the "app/console cache" part to "php app/console cache" stops the app error.

Then go to appengine-symfony-starter-project\app\config and rename "parameters.yml.dist" to "parameters.yml.

For me that resolves the app problem.

Comment: These changes partially solved the problem.  Now when the dev_appserver.py starts to run, I get a `memcache` error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Cache\Exception\CacheException' with message 'Memcached >= 2.2.0 is required' in C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\test2\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Cache\Traits\MemcachedTrait.php:77

Comment: I have the same problem and am still looking into it. I isntalled memcache using a custom dll for php 7.2 but symfony does not recognise it, or it is asking for "memcached" specifically and will not except memcache, but parts of the symfony on GAE are specifying memcache and some specify memcached, so I am not sure which it wants and have found conflicting results online.

Comment: Did you enable memcached extension for php cli?